# Restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, pdfsharp, visual-studio-2019

I installed a Visual Studio 2019 and created a new Asp.Net core 2.1 console application project. I was trying to install NuGet package 'PDFsharp 1.50.5147' and it always gave me this warning. I have changed it to the previous versions but same things happened.

tried to match older versions of PdfSharp with .NET version 2.1 and also tired with .NET version 2.0

[warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne95f.png)

Comment: What warning was it? Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: Use the PdfSharpCore package instead.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the warning message. Used PdfSharpCore and it worked @HansPassant